# Publishing update with no db changes

Tags: android, sqlite, google-play

I'm pretty sure I understand this correctly, but want to verify and see if I'm missing anything before publishing an update in the Android Market.

Version 1 (active in the market) creates and manipulates a local sqlite db.

Version 1.1 does nothing different in regards to the db - my ultimate goal is to reuse the db from version 1 (structure and data).

My understanding is that updates will perform whatever is in `onUpgrade`, assuming the database version has changed.

So if version 1.1 uses the same value for the db version number:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

..then the database from version 1 will maintained and reused in 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. If the database version is the same the `onUpgrade` method is not executed.